# Lo Shu Magic square

Tags: python

My task is:

> The Lo Shu Magic Square is a grid with 3 rows and 3 columns. The Lo
>   Shu Magic Square has the following properties:
>
> • The grid contains the numbers 1 through 9 exactly.
>
> • The sum of each row, each column, and each diagonal all add up to
>   the same number.
>
> In a program you can simulate a magic square using a two-dimensional
>   list. Write a function that accepts a two-dimensional list as an
>   argument and determines whether the list is a Lo Shu Magic Square.
>
> Test the function in a program.

I wrote this code but Im sure that its in right way.

```
ROWS=3
COLS=3

def main():
    values=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
    for r in range(ROWS):
        for c in range(COLS):
            print('Enter number ', c + 1)
            values[r][c]=int(input('Enter your number'))
        if values[0][0] + values[0][1] + values[0][2] == values[1][0] + values[1][1] + values[1][2] == values[1][0] \
                + values[1][1] + values[1][2] == values[2][0] + values[2][1] + values[2][2] == values[0][2] \
                + values[1][2] + values[2][2] == values[0][0] + values[1][1] + values[2][2]:
            print ('there is magic square')
    print(values)
main()
```

Comment: Hey and welcome! What is your question?

Comment: Is your output a valid magic square? What is wrong with your current function?

Comment: Did you remember to check all 3 columns, 3 rows, and 2 diagonals? (HINT: one of those is missing)

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't follow the specs:

> Write a function that accepts a two-dimensional list as an argument and determines whether the list is a Lo Shu Magic Square.

So you should first have something like:

```
def is_magic_square(2dlist):
    # code here to check if `2dlist` is a magic square
    # I leave it to you to put the correct code here...
    return result # where result is either `True` or `False`
```

> Test the function in a program.

here you want to call your function with a set of 2d lists that you know are magic squares or not, and check the function returns the right result, ie:

```
def main():
    goods = [
        # here a list of 2d lists known to be magic squares
    ]

    bads = [
        # here a list of 2d lists known to NOT be magic squares
        # HINT: add a 2d list that is all zeros. It isn't a magic square; Does the test return False?

    ]

    for candidate in goods:
        if not is_magic_square(candidate):
            print("error: {} should be a magic square".format(candidate))

    for candidate in bads:
        if is_magic_square(candidate):
            print("error: {} should NOT be a magic square".format(candidate))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is basically known as unit testing, and is a very valuable tool for programming.